# how to implement search functionality from multiple tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using search functionality from different tables,

already i have implemented search functionality for diiferent fields from one table by using predicate

example:-

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<My_prj_project>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Prj_project_name.Equals(name));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
    predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Prj_project_address.Equals(address));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact))
    predicate = predicate.And(e1 => e1.Prj_project_contact.Equals(contact));
```

In this way but now i need from from tables i need to search.

So can you please send me sample (or) example

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The "other tables" are related to this "My_prj_project"?  If so, using EF you can access those tables through navigation properties on your model.

Comment: Thanks for giving reply, But the tables are related to the same context but i dont have how to use EF so can you send me sample are any related link.

Answer (score 0):

To make efficient searching you can also create a stored procedure inside the database and pass to it the search phrase. In stored procedure you can choose conditions, tables and fields - however you need.